# How to access PHP SimpleXMLElement attributes?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

This is my xml object. I am unable to parse this in object array in my script.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object(
[pagination] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [pageNumber] => 1
                [pageSize] => 100
                [totalAvailable] => 1
            )

    )

[users] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => xxxxxxxx
                        [name] => xxxxx
                        [siteRole] => xxxxx
                        [lastLogin] => xxxxxx
                        [externalAuthUserId] =>
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
foreach($xml2->users as $item) { 
$userName = $item->attributes()->name;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at example number 5 here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks! Silly mistake. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. Here is the modified code:

```
foreach($xml2->users[0] as $user) { 
    $userName = $user['name'];
}
```

Thanks to ymas he pointed correctly.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Both forms are technically correct, although I agree that the `['name']` format is neater. It's a borderline edit, though, because it completely changes the OP's answer.

Comment: @IMSoP good point, it was an extreme edit.  However, the original answer will return a SimpleXMLElement Object, rather than a string value, no?

Comment: @StevenMoseley No, `$foo->attributes()->bar` and `$foo['bar']` return exactly the same object. https://3v4l.org/a3tQo If you want the string value, you have to cast to string, e.g. `$userName = (string)$user['name'];`